# Use a variable to store data from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-engines

I've got a small Rails app with my own engines. Each of the engines is supposed to load a yaml file that should be used by the Rails app. I figured the best way was to use store each gem's yaml file into a constant inside an initializer, which would make those constants and hence the file available to the Rails app. Now I've got more gems which will do the same. Is there a way by which I can initialize an array (as a global I imagine) within the Rails app, that would be accessible by the dependent gems and add those file paths (constant) to the itself. Then I can just iterate over this global instead of having to call each gem's initialized constant. Where exactly would be the best place to place such a constant? It would need to be initialized before gem initialization.

Comment: I put the global in boot.rb, and it does work, but I'm unsure if that's the right way to go forward. In fact, is there an alternative to using the global?

Comment: The gem FrozenRecord might be helpful for you: https://github.com/byroot/frozen_record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `config/application.rb`. That file defines a class you can use to set and get custom configuration parameters. Give something like this a try:

```
# config/application.rb
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.yaml_stuff = {}
  end
end

# my_plugin/config/initializers/load_yaml_data.rb
MyApp::Application.config.yaml_suff[:my_plugin] = YAML.load_file('whatever.yml')
```